# Regex Replacement Dependent On Class

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have the following code that replaces all  tags on a page and adds the nCode image resizer to it. The code is as follows:

```
function ncode_the_content($content) {
return preg_replace("/<img([^`|>]*)>/im", "<img onload=\"NcodeImageResizer.createOn(this);\"$1>", $content); }

}
```

What I need to do is make it so that if an image has the class of "noresize" it doesn't do the preg_match.

I have only managed to get it so that if there is the "noresize" class anywhere on the page it stops resizing all images instead of just the one with the correct class.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Am I even remotely in the right ballpark with this?

```
function ncode_the_content($content) {

//Load the HTML page
$html = file_get_contents($content);
//Parse it. Here we use loadHTML as a static method
//to parse the HTML and create the DOM object in one go.
@$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);

//Init the XPath object
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

//Query the DOM
$linksnoresize = $xpath->query( 'img[@class = "noresize"]' );
$links = $xpath->query( 'img[]' );

//Display the results as in the previous example
foreach($links as $link){
echo $link->getAttribute('onload'), 'NcodeImageResizer.createOn(this);';
}

foreach($linksnoresize as $link){
echo $link->getAttribute('onload'), '';
}
  }
```

Comment: Don't parse XML with regexes. Use an XML parser instead (like [`DOMDocument`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)). DOMDocument would also make the problem trivial.

Comment: How would I go about doing this cause I'm trying to edit a WP plugin here.

Comment: DOMDocument's documentation is pretty good at explaining such things.

Comment: Really not getting this :l

Updated first post.

Comment: You know, XPath supports negation too `'//img[@class!="noresize"]'` would return all the right elements, then you can just add the attribute to them. Not sure what the `echo` is for though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using pure CSS and adding a  around the images I didn't want to be resized. Forced the width and height of that div back to auto and then removed the warning message that was displayed above them. Seems to work fine. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some untested code:

```
$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML($content);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if (!strstr($image->getAttribute("class"), "noresize")) {
        $image->setAttribute("onload", "NcodeImageResizer.createOn(this);");
    }
}
```

But, if it were me, I would eschew any such inline event handler and instead just find the appropriate elements with Javascript.

Comment: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::setAttribute()

Comment: @user1544348 I accidentally a letter.